# Error when creating list views filtered by a column containing hyperlinks

Tags: workflow, list-view

I am trying to create a list view where I filter by a column containing a hyperlink. When I create the view this error "HRESULT: 0x80131904" shows in the list.

Comment: Can you provide some more info such as SharePoint version, how many columns in the list, how many list items, etc.?

Comment: Version: 15.1.11.0
There are 25 columns in the list and 40 items.
The column I am trying to filter by is the workflow status hyperlink "Completed", "In Progress" that when clicked takes you to the workflow status page for that item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a known issue with various versions of SharePoint when you try to filter by a workflow status. Instead of filtering by the string `Complete` or `In Progress`, etc. in the Filter section of the view, you'll need to use the integer value for the workflow string in the Filter section. Here are workflow status integer values:

- NotStarted = 0
- FailedOnStart = 1
- InProgress = 2
- ErrorOccurred = 3
- StoppedByUser = 4
- Completed = 5
- FailedOnStartRetrying = 6
- ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7
- ViewQueryOverflow = 8
- Rejected = 17
- Approved = 16
- Canceled = 15

More documentation about this is at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/925425